# How to cound how many times a condition is true until it is not true on average in r?

Tags: r

i'm trying to comb thru stock data and I usually use Java but not good enough for what I'll eventually build out. In R, how can I check how many times a condition is true until its false on average 
so if X> 10 = true
   if x < 10 = false

how many times is x > 10 until its below

Comment: Try `sum(x > 10)`  Not clear about the expected output.  It is better to provide a small example

Comment: Or maybe `match(TRUE, x < 10) - 1`? Hard to tell quite what you mean, especially by "false on average". Share some sample data and your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently started using R and (if I correctly understood your question) I incurred in a similar problem(s).

First I am generating a sample of 1000 elements with random values between 0 and 20 (I chose 20 simply because your condition would be <> 10, hence I took 10 as the middle point)

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(n=runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20), group = 0)
> x
#               n group
#1    18.01267749     0
#2     8.50561210     0
#3    11.26424876     0
#4     1.22902009     0
#5    17.37173610     0
#6    15.79453081     0
#7     4.84231228     0
#8     1.36992180     0
#9     2.16605579     0
#10   16.51773243     0
...
```

I am not sure what you mean specifically but I will try to solve two problems:
1- Count how many rows meet a certain conditio and how many do not.
2- Check how many consecutive "rows" meet a certain condition until the condition is not met anymore.

Now for the first case, thinking in a "programming" way with for-loops:

```r
res2 <- c(0,0)
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  if(x[[i,"n"]] > 10)
    res2[1] <- res2[1]+1
  else
    res2[2] <- res2[2]+1
}
#> res2
#[1] 494 506
```

Of course there is a better and **faster** way to do it, the "R" way:

```r
res <- x %>%
    group_by(group = if_else(x$n > 10, 1, 0)) %>%
    summarise(total = n())
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  group total
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     0   506
#2     1   494
```

The idea is simple: Put all the rows with a value >10 in a group (identified by 1, and rows with `n` <10 in another group identified by 0), then group with the variable `group` and finally count the total rows in the two groups.

Now for the second case, which is *slightly* harder if one does not have the right tools. It actually took me a while back then to find the right answer without using for-loops.

The idea is to use [rle](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/rle), or run-length encoding:

```r
x$group <- with(rle(x$n < 10), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
#> x
#               n group
#1    18.01267749     1
#2     8.50561210     2
#3    11.26424876     3
#4     1.22902009     4
#5    17.37173610     5
#6    15.79453081     5
#7     4.84231228     6
#8     1.36992180     6
#9     2.16605579     6
#10   16.51773243     7
#11    2.22784827     8
#12   19.44676961     9
#13    1.28190206    10
#14   15.93426880    11
#15   16.70963107    11
#16    5.01572254    12
```

What `rle` does is to generate a new group index whenever there is a change in the condition result. So if there are 3 values in a row which are all < 10, they will all have the same group index, but as soon as a value does not meet the condition anymore, a the group index increases.

You can notice in the example as rows 5-6 are both >10, and their group has index `5`, but row 7 is <10 so the new group index is `6`, and so on...

Now, since the group index changes everytime the condition result changes, in order to know how many times it does change, you can just get the largest group index and divide by two.

```r
> max(x$group)/2
# [1] 242
```

You can test that by doing:

```r
runLength <- rle(x$n < 10)$values
res <- length(runLength[runLength == TRUE])
#> res
#[1] 242
```

Answer (score 0):

I produced data using `runif` like @Gabryxx7, but this solution is a one-liner (I think this is what you were looking for anyway).

```
# Data
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(n=runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20))

# Solution
mean(rle(x$n > 10)$lengths[rle(x$n > 10)$values == T])
[1] 2.020492
```

I'll explain what's going on. The `x$n > 10` part outputs `TRUE` if the values in column n in object x are greater than 10. It's really that simple.

Here it is step by step.

```
# Create column in x for whether value is greater than 10
x$GreaterThanTen <- x$n > 10

# Input rle output into object
ConsecutiveVars <- rle(x$GreaterThanTen)

ConsecutiveVars$lengths # (1 1 1 2 1) Tells us some value occurs consecutively: once, once, once, twice, once, etc.
ConsecutiveVars$values # (F T F T F) Tells us which values occur consecutively: FALSE then TRUE then FALSE then TRUE then FALSE, etc.

# so FALSE occurs once, then TRUE occurs once, then FALSE occurs once, then TRUE occurs twice, then FALSE occurs once, etc.

# We want to know only how many times TRUE occurs consecutively, so we filter ConsecutiveVars$lengths for when it is TRUE
ConsecutiveTRUES <- ConsecutiveVars$lengths[ConsecutiveVars$values == T]

# Then take the average
mean(ConsecutiveTRUES)
2.020492
```